# String manipulation & PDF output file

Tags: javascript, html, string

I have a HTML file that is used to produce a PDF and gets a date from a previous page - screen selection.

It is about string manipulation (extraction a substring that starts with “[“ from a string and displaying the result).

Example: instead of "Van4[15]" it is supposed to display "Van4".

```
[RoomName]=Van4[15]
```

The HTML file is:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function extract() {
      var str = "van6[15]";
      return str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("["));
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = extract();
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="extract()">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center; font-size:60; font-family:Verdana; font-weight:bold;border:1px solid Black;">
        <p id="demo"></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't get what "PDF" in your title has to do with this question. I also don't get what the question is, so that may be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the replace method on the string object using RegEx. I'm not sure if there's any variation, but for the example you gave in the initial post I think this should help:

```
var mystring = '[RoomName]=Van4[15]';
var myNewString = mystring.replace(`/.+=(.+)\[.+/g`, '$1');

console.log(myNewString);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ejzg32jr/

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, using RegEx it is another option. My code is correct and verified on jsfiddle.net . The problem is, this HTM  file that it is used to create the PDF output file and on top of this PDF file it is displayed the content between <script></script> tags-> 
      function extract() {
        var str = "Van5 [14]";
        return str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("["));
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = extract();
    My question is, how to display the result of this function not the content between the <script> tags

Comment: @DanyV I apologize but I am having a hard time understanding what you're asking for. I created this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x8nc7ace/ - is what you are asking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5ud8jkvf/ ?

Comment: @DanyV A running example would be : http://jsfiddle.net/5ud8jkvf/6912/ - it uses jsPDF which is a JS library that you can grab here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jspdf

Comment: It is a: ASP.Net MVC webpage. The view has a grid with Location , CourseName.... and a checkbox for PDFprinting .The records/data on the grid comes from SQL db. and this Location field data contains for couple of records at the end "[number]"  If the user select the checkbox for one record after clicking on "Print into PDF " button should produce the PDF file .

Comment: The code behind Print button starts with:
public ActionResult ReportsPDF(PrintFormReportModel Obj)
        {
            string HTMLFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Views/Reports/RoomSignReport.htm"); Where this file RoomSignReport.htm is the one that I am trying to modify by extracting the substring that contains[..] form the Location data ) Thank you once again

Comment: Everything is working, only the task was to extract the substring that contains[number] , the reason why I came up with idea of using the function extract(). Unfortunately using the <script> function extract(..</script> displays at the top of PDF file the content of <script> tag instead of displaying the result here :  <p id="demo"></p> I hope these details helps

Comment: Sorry, if my explanations weren’t very clear, because was too much to explain I just tried to make it simpler and just focusing on the string manipulation. I hope the above details helps. Thank you once again

Comment: Maybe it is useful to mention, it uses iTextSharp, a .NET PDF library for creating the PDF file

Comment: @DanyV Apologies, but then I can't help. You may have better luck reposting this question under the appropriate category of .NET and such.