# String manipulation/extract a substring & PDF file produced from a HTML file using iTextSharp, a .NET PDF library for creating the PDF file

Tags: javascript, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, itext

I have an issue with using iTextSharp and String manipulation/extract a substring that contains “[number]” and producing the PDF file. My previous question was posted here:
    [String manipulation & PDF output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479841/string-manipulation-pdf-output-file)

I am using this function to extract the substring that contains "[..]"

```
<script>
</script>

<script>
function extract() {
  var str = "van4[15]";
  return str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("["));
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = extract(); </script>
```

It is a: ASP.Net MVC webpage. The view has a grid with Location , RoomName.... and a checkbox for  PDF printing. The records/data on the grid comes from SQL db. This Location field data contains for couple of records at the end "[number]". If the user select the checkbox for one record after clicking on "Print into PDF " button should produce the PDF file.

I am using `string contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HTMLFilePath)` to read the file where Location, RoomName. It is part of this Html file.

The code behind Print button starts with:

```
public ActionResult ReportsPDF(PrintFormReportModel Obj) { string HTMLFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Views/Reports/RoomSignReport.htm");
```

Where this file RoomSignReport.htm is the one that I am trying to modify by extracting the substring that contains[..] form the Location data ). The task is to extract the substring that contains [number] , the reason why I came up with idea of using the function extract(). Unfortunately using the `<script>` function extract(..`</script>` displays at the top of PDF file the content of `<script>` tag instead of displaying the result here : `<p id="demo"></p>`

Answer (score 0):

I solve this task by myself. For anyone that might need help with this topic, I am adding the code snippet here:

```
if (ReportList.Count > 0)
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Report, new FileStream(FullPath, FileMode.Create));
    Report.Open();
    try
    {
        if (ListRoomSign.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var ObjReportList in ReportList)
            {
                foreach (var ObjRoomSignList in ListRoomSign)
                {
                    .....
                    string contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HTMLFilePath);

                    //Remove square brackets value from room name
                    if (ObjReportList.Location.Contains("["))
                    {
                        ObjReportList.Location = ObjReportList.Location.ToString().Substring(0, ObjReportList.Location.ToString().LastIndexOf("["));
                    }
                    //
                    contents = contents.Replace("[RoomName]", ObjReportList.Location);
                    var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(contents), null);
                    foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
                    {
                        Report.Add(htmlElement as IElement);
                    }
                    Report.NewPage();                                        
                }
            }   
        }

        Report.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        FullPath = string.Empty;
    }
}
return FullPath;
```